# Getting IO error while connecting to the DB2 server installed in AIX machine

Tags: java, jdbc

I am facing serious problem when I try to use the connection pool object to execute the query in DB2. My application is deployed in WebSphere 7 and sits on AIX box and 
DB2 is running another AIX box. The problem is intermittent. When I searched the `server.log` file I got below exception captured.

```
java.net.SocketException: There is no process to read data written to a pipe. at 
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) at 
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:103) at 
java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:147) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.b(fb.java:1685) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.a(fb.java:1633) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.D(a.java:416) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.r(a.java:380) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.n.a(n.java:219) at
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.go.b(go.java:4302) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.go.fc(go.java:741) at 
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.go.executeQuery(go.java:711)
```

But If I try to create a connection object, the above issue is not occurring, only problem in existing connection pool object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been fixed it after analyzing the connection object. Basically issue with connection pool object sometimes, the connection object will not be closed, but system IO might be causing above issues. To fix the issue , just validate connection using JDBC Api connection.isValid(0) . If you provide value as o , it means no timeout specified for execution, basically above methods verifies connection pipeline is working as expected. If it returns true then no issue, we can use same object  it returns false, then write a proper logic to create a connection object.